# Raspberry Pi Zero W dashboard project (Raspbian with Pixel is incredibly slow)

Tags: pi-zero-w

I just have bought:

- Raspberry Pi Zero W (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-zero-w/)
- BenQ GS2870H display (Full HD, 28" display)
- SanDisk Ultra microSDHC 32GB (https://www.amazon.de/SanDisk-Ultra-microSDHC-Class-Speicherkarte/dp/B007JTKLEK)

What I want to achieve is creating a simple dashboard (for example based on NODE.JS server) with notifications from Asana, Facebook/Messenger, Workmail/Private Mails, To-Do List and whiteboard with possibility of drawing on it during meetings.

I have few questions/issues:

1. Is it possible to make it a little faster as even turning on Raspbian Control Panel is "a a pain in the backside" ;)? Maybe I am missing some boot configuration or using wrong OS? I have installed that one available from NOOBS Offline Installer.
2. Can some of you recommend me something similar to Magic Mirror? As it is not recommended to use it on Raspbian Pi Zero W?
3. Maybe I am using a wrong browser and I should not use Chromium?

Much thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If it is incredibly slow it is overloaded.  Perhaps a Raspberry Pi is not the right computer for the job?

Comment: Hi @joan! Thanks for your comment. :)
I was thinking about it but it was suspicious for me that even opening control panel or writing in the browser URL field is working so slow. That is why I am asking.

Comment: You are asking too broad a question here, or rather too many questions, you might be able to get more helpful responses by splitting them up and researching each one separately (e.g. "Chromium on the RPi Zero" as one, "Raspian replacement for *Magic Mirror*", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this, but I've just been reading an article about how to do this using [DAKBoard](http://dakboard.com/site) on a Pi Zero W [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpgradingTheDakBoardFamilyCalendarWithRaspberryPiZeroWAndReadOnlyFilesystem.aspx). It will not work as a whiteboard but should handle everything else, and performance doesn't seem to be an issue.